# Applying JSON style from URL to Vector in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, style, json, url

Can the `style` be a URL in OpenLayers?

```
var layer_offline = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
    declutter: true,
    source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
      format: new ol.format.MVT(),
      url: 'http://localhost/tile?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}'
    }),
    style: ???? // <--- This one I would need to load a JSON file
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to use the [ol-mapbox-style](https://npmjs.com/package/ol-mapbox-style) plugin. It has an API that allows you to use [Mapbox Style](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/) JSONs as style for a specific layer (like in your snippet), but it also allows you to create a whole map from a Mapbox Style document.

What you want is probably something along these lines:

```
var layer_offline = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
  declutter: true,
  source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
    format: new ol.format.MVT(),
    url: 'http://localhost/tile?z={z}&x={x}&y={y}'
  })
});
layer_offline.setStyle(olms.stylefunction(layer_offline, style_json, 'mysource');
```

where `layer_offline` is the Mapbox Style JSON, and `mysource` is the id of the source from that style JSON you want to render.

Comment: Is there any performance gain as compared to Openlayer's `styleFunction`?

Comment: No. Internally, ol-mapbox-style also uses a `styleFunction`.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Keep up the great work! Hopefully in the future versions, there will be an improvement :)